# Docker Swarm x AWS ALB x Traefik - HTTP 504 error being returned

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm, traefik

We have a Docker Swarm cluster that utilizes Traefik to take care of routing requests to the correct service in the cluster. Out of the box, this works properly. However, when an AWS Application Load Balancer was integrated into the infrastructure (to prepare for AWS Web Application Firewall implementation), services became unreachable. See below:

[image: ALB x Docker Swarm]

The idea is that ALB requests go through one of the nodes and then goes to Traefik (port 80) and it routes to the correct Docker container.

Security group misconfiguration is not the issue because when running Nginx as a stand-alone container (`docker run -p 80:80 nginx`) and accessible through port 80, the ALB is able to access the service successfully.

At first we thought it was an IPv6 issue but disabling IPv6 in the host did not solve anything.

**Update:** Changing the configuration of Traefik like the one below made it work. I'm not quite sure why this is needed when using ALB.

```
 ports:
  - target: 80
    published: 80
    protocol: tcp
    mode: host
```

Comment: could inidcate an issue with your ingress network. Check if required ports are open. When you use mode host, you are are not using the ingress network for that service.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought at first. However, I have opened all traffic to 7946 (TCP/UDP), 4789 (UDP) for all hosts within that private network.

Answer (score -1):

hey @jackeblagare do you mind share your entire traefik configuration? we are trying to have the same setup

Route53 entry which point to the ALB DNS  + Docker Swarm cluster + traefik / services but it seems that we need to change something because with this current setup the traefik dont receive any traffic and we got time out
if we use NLB with just TCP Listener/HC's work perfect.

I dont think that we need to open any ports because as test purposes we are using a security group that has all ports open ( i know that's not recommended but it's on a sandbox environment )

thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately the sole workaround that worked here is to disable port 443 for Traefik and  the corresponding services. See edit in the original question. You need to specify that Traefik should only use port 80. Then for the services, just remove any http to https redirect.